# tidesdk exception when using forms

Tags: php, tidesdk

I have a simple tidesdk program with php module which contains a simple form and a php file which handles this form.

Everything works fine. But when I submit the form the program crashes and throws an exception which is listed below.

I am running the program through tidesdk developer.

Here's the form.

```
<form action="login.php">
                        <table style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                                         </span>
                                        <input name="username" class="form-control custom-input" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="focusedInput">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                    <div class="input-group"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                                         </span>
                                        <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                        <input id='loginSubmit' name='loginSubmit' type="hidden" value="<?php print md5(time()); ?>">
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                    <button name="login" id="login" type="submit" class="btn-inverse button-custom" data-section="2">
                                        Sign In
                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Here's the php file that handles the form.

```
 <?php 

      print_r($_GET);

?>
```

**And this is the exception I am getting.**

```
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
```

I am running this on Windows 8 Pro - 64 bit. But I have also tried this on 32 bit version of XP and Windows 7 but got the same exception.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the full trace of the application.

```
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\hsm-test\dist\win32\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_d08a11e2442dc25d\msvcp80.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_d08a11e2442dc25d\msvcr80.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\tide.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoFoundation.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\WebKit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\icuuc40.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\libproxy.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\CFLite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\JavaScriptCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\libcurl.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\libxml2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\icuin40.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\icudt40.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\pthreadVC2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\libeay32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\ssleay32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\zlib1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\app\1.3.1-beta\tideapp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoUtil.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoXML.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\codec\1.3.1-beta\tidecodec.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoZip.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\database\1.3.1-beta\tidedatabase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoData.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoSQLite.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\filesystem\1.3.1-beta\tidefilesystem.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\media\1.3.1-beta\tidemedia.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\monkey\1.3.1-beta\tidemonkey.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\network\1.3.1-beta\tidenetwork.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\PocoNet.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\platform\1.3.1-beta\tideplatform.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\runtime\win32\1.3.1-beta\cairo.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\process\1.3.1-beta\tideprocess.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\ui\1.3.1-beta\tideui.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.16384_none_a9f4965301334e09\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\worker\1.3.1-beta\tideworker.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\php\1.3.1-beta\tidephp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\php\1.3.1-beta\php5ts.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\php\1.3.1-beta\php_gd2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\php\1.3.1-beta\php_curl.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mlang.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0xf80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
First-chance exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
The thread 0x1d50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x738573BD (msvcr80.dll) in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88001200.
```

Comment: The issue looks like you do not have the proper run-time files installed for Visual Studio. Check this page for more information: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555. By the way you may want to try out Nightrain instead. http://nightrain.naetech.com/ Tidesdk's support for PHP is quite buggy, so you might run into other issues.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Runtime (both 64 and 32 bit) packages all ready installed. I also tried on two different machines and got the same error. But thanks for suggesting an alternative. Any idea on how can I create an installation package using nightrain?

Comment: Currently Nightrain doesn't seem to offer a installer since the aim is to make an application as portable as possible. However, what I suggest is after you have finished developing your application and tested it with Nightrain, use a tool like InstallShield (http://www.installshield.com/) or InstallBuilder (http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) to create a installer for the end product. There are some free ones too but usually you are very limited to those. InstallBuilder by BitRock would be best for cross platform deployment! InstallBuilder is a little pricey but worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925920/en-us) :

> When you run a Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) application, you may
> receive an access violation error message.
>
> Typically, this problem occurs if the following conditions are true:
>
> - The name of the folder in which the MFC application runs contains the
>   percent symbol (%).
> - You create the MFC application under your profile
>   folder.

You seem to have your project in your user folder :

```
C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\hsm-test\dist\win32\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.exe
```

Still quoting :

> ### Hotfix information
>
> A supported hotfix is now available from Microsoft, but it is only
> intended to correct the problem that is described in this article.
> Only apply it to systems that are experiencing this specific problem.
> This hotfix may receive additional testing. Therefore, if you are not
> severely affected by this problem, we recommend that you wait for the
> next Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 service pack that contains this
> hotfix.
>
> To resolve this problem immediately, contact Microsoft Product Support
> Services to obtain the hotfix. For a complete list of Microsoft
> Product Support Services telephone numbers and information about
> support costs, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
> http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But everything apart from the form variables works in the same location. I've also tried moving the project and still got the same error. I've also build an installer and installed it on XP, Windows 7 and got the same error.

Comment: @JayBhatt Did you try to move it away of your User folder?

Comment: Yes. When I installed it, the location of the program was "c:\Program Files\xxxx"

Comment: @JayBhatt Ok, sorry... I'll leave this answer anyway, so future visitors won't post the same.